# Blog posts not listing under Wagtail homepage

Tags: django, wagtail

I've been successful in setting up the development server up to this tutorial:

http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.9/getting_started/tutorial.html

I'm currently at the step "Create a template at `blog/templates/blog/blog_page.html`:" and I'm able to create child pages that go in homepage/blog/blog-post but they aren't listing in homepage/blog as they do in the tutorial. I can't figure out why and I've tried playing with changing where the blog posts show up by placing them in homepage/blog as blog posts but still nothing.

I think I'm not understanding what needs to be done here:

```
from django.db import models

from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import Page
from wagtail.wagtailcore.fields import RichTextField
from wagtail.wagtailadmin.edit_handlers import FieldPanel
from wagtail.wagtailsearch import index


# Keep the definition of BlogIndexPage, and add:


class BlogPage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('intro'),
        index.SearchField('body'),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('intro'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
    ]
```

More specifically, `# Keep the definition of BlogIndexPage, and add:`.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `Keep the definition of BlogIndexPage, and add` means that the implementation (the class) of the `BlogIndexPage` is not repeated in the code snippet for clarity (so you focus on the new `BlogPage` class being introduced) and space, but you should leave the `BlogIndexPage` class definition in the file.
In other words, `models.py` should contain both `BlogIndexPage` and `BlogPage` classes (and all the imports).

Edit: If that's already what you have, please share the full content of your `blog/models.py` and `blog/templates/blog/blog_index_page.html`.

Comment: @LoïcTeixeira I believe I have. Here is the models.py > http://pastebin.com/8hyxezHv / blog_index_page.html > http://pastebin.com/VrhPxg8V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The homepage doesn't list blog posts until I manually import that from the page itself. They're all listed under /blog, where the guide intends for it to show up until you change it to also list under the homepage, which I will eventually set up. Thanks everyone.